# Shellexecute mysql with command line to import a SQL file

Tags: mysql, windows, command-line, cmd, shellexecute

If I type this into command window:

```
"D:\databases\MySQL-5_0(x64)\bin\mysql.exe" -u root betting < "W:\data\projects\temp\example.sql"
```

**That works**

Next task is running above from my own computer program...

**1)**
Using shellexecute directly to call mysql with above parameters does not work for me. Studying SO I found that the reason is CMD doing the pipe > stuff.

**2)**
Call shellexecute on **cmd.exe** wih params being

**cmd /c "D:\databases\MySQL-5_0(x64)\bin\mysql.exe" -u root betting < "W:\data\projects\temp\example.sql"**

Delphi code example:

```
  S := '"D:\databases\MySQL-5_0(x64)\bin\mysql.exe" -u root betting < "W:\data\projects\temp\example.sql"';
  S := '/c ' + S;
  ShellExecute(
    0,
    'open',
    'cmd.exe',
    PChar(S),
    nil,
    SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED
  );
```

Does not work either.

To see what the problem was, I tried putting the following into an already open command line prompt window like this:

```
cmd.exe /c "D:\databases\MySQL-5_0(x64)\bin\mysql.exe" -u root betting < "W:\data\projects\temp\example.sql"
```

which gives error

> 'D:\databases\MySQL-5_0' is not recognized as an internal or external
>   command, operable program or batch file.

This puzzled me as my usage of double-quotes should be correct. But trying this instead:

```
cmd.exe /c "mysql.exe" -u root betting < "W:\data\projects\temp\example.sql"
```

still gives an error:

> 'mysql.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

I have reached the end of the line of things to try I think.

Can anyone shed some light on how to successfully execute mysql from a program passing a commandline instruction ha instructs mysql to execute a SQL file?

Comment: CMD has special quote rules. See `cmd /?`. You are missing the last quote around the input file (CMD ignores this but it is wrong and other programs mightn't). You have to put `cmd /c`, not just `/c`. `cmd /c "D:\databases\MySQL-5_0(x64)\bin\mysql.exe" -u root betting < "W:\data\projects\temp\example.sql"`

Comment: Both things fixed in question now - no change in result though / error messages :(

Comment: ShellExecute is a function. Should be a COM error code. Rename the folder so no brackets.

Comment: Typing this in command prompt which was equalant of the shellexecute does not work either: cmd.exe /c "mysql.exe" -u root betting < "W:\data\projects\temp\example.sql" (I hope solving that will also solve shellexecute usage)

Comment: You are confused, by prefixing cmd /c you no longer shellexecute - you send it to CMD. Read the Docs on CreateProcess and ShellExecute.

Comment: I have tried Shellexecute mysql directly (pipes not work - otherwise works fine of course, but need pipes), shellexecute cmd.exe with params 'cmd /c "D:\databases\MySQL-5_0(x64)\bin\mysql.exe" -u root betting < "W:\data\projects\temp\example.sql"' and shellexecute cmd.exe with params '/c "D:\databases\MySQL-5_0(x64)\bin\mysql.exe" -u root betting < "W:\data\projects\temp\example.sql"'. I will try understand why the manually typing in CMD window with 'cmd.exe /c "mysql.exe" -u root betting < "W:\data\projects\temp\example.sql"' fails as well. Migh help explain why shellexecute also not works.

Comment: Remove the brackets from the foldername. CMD doesn't look up the AppPaths key which shellexecute does. By passing it to CMD you loses the ability to use short names.

Comment: For what i is worth. I did so my software creates a .bat file on the fly containing the full paths with spaces in "", params etc. and then shellexecute that. I appreciate all the help, but I never could i working any other way for whatever the reason. @Noodles I will upvote some of your commens. Thanks again for trying to help